# 301 redirect help - .htm removed and few urls changed

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I'm moving content from an old dreamweaver site to a new wordpress site, all file names are the same, except the new wordpress one's don't have the .htm at the end.

Some category/subcats slugs are changed.

I'm wanting to 301 the domain and all pages to new domain name.

Most urls:

Old content url:   http://olddomain.com/reviews/soft/graphics/filename.htm

Where new page will be: http://newdomain.com/reviews/soft/graphics/filename

A few categories/subcats:

Old: http:// olddomain.com/reviews/hard/sound/filename.htm

New: http:// newdomain.com/reviews/hard/sound-review/filename

What would the 301 htaccess file look like?

(note: both old and new urls have the www. in them, the old domain also needs all non-www redirected too)

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

> What would the 301 htaccess file look like?

In the htaccess file in your `olddomain.com` document root:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)\.htm$ http://newdomain.com/$1/$2/$3/$4
```

Comment: @MaxBramwell THis matches `/anything/anything/anything/anything.htm`. Only the `/` and `.htm` is  constant